# SoundCloud API - SC.stream does not work

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

I am trying to use stream function as displayed on example(taken from SDK http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript)

```
SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
  sound.play();
});
```

But it does not work and gives 404 error:
GET http://connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Have you tried to do a hard refresh in the browser you are developing in?

Answer (score 0):

As of the JavaScript SDK version 3.3.0, this is working as intended.  Make sure to initialize the SoundCloud client with your Client ID:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: '{CLIENT_ID}'
});

SC.stream('tracks/293').then(function(player) {
    player.play();
});
```